# Using bash to search for a string in the second column

Tags: bash, awk, user-input

I'm trying to write a function that looks for a last name (from user input) in the second column and returns the line to the user.  Here is what I've tried (and is not working).  Most importantly, when I run this with the last name in place of $input_name at the command line, it works then.  As you can see, the echo to confirm that the user input was read properly.  What am I missing?

```
 60 last_search () {
 61         echo "What last name are you looking for?"
 62         read input_name
 63         echo "$input_name"
 64         awk -F':' '$2 ~ /$input_name/{print $0}' temp_phonebook
 65 }
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `-v name=value` to pass a shell variable to awk
2. Shell variable won't be expanded in single quote
3. `print $0` is default action so take it out.

You can use:

```
awk -F: -v input_name="$input_name" '$2 ~ input_name' temp_phonebook
```

Comment: This is the correct way to pass the value of a shell variable to an awk script so +` but for the OP - do you REALLY want to print lines where $2 CONTAINS the input_name (e.g. does $2 Johnson match input_name John?) as the above script would do or when $2 is EXACTLY the input_name? If the latter replace `~` with `==`.

Answer (score -1):

Your awk command is in single ticks, so `$input_name` never gets expanded.

Try something like this:

```
awk -F':' '$2 ~ /'"$input_name"'/{print $0}' temp_phonebook
```

Alternately, supply the value in advance using `-v name=value`:

```
awk -F':' -v search="${input_name}" '$2 ~ search {print $0}' temp_phonebook
```

Comment: This breaks when the input name is, for example, `Mr. Llama`, with a space between the words.  At minimum, enclose `"$input_name"` in double quotes.

Comment: So I should use double quotes?  I get:awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
  >>>  ~ <<< 
awk: bailing out at source line 1

Comment: I tried: awk -F':' '$2 ~ /"$input_name"/{print $0}' temp_phonebook but it isn't working either

Comment: Use the `-v name=value` method, it's much more reliable.  Note that the first example is single-quote then double-quote.

Answer (score -1):

okay, I figured it out!  I need single quotes around the variable  '$input_name'

Comment: 1. This is not a valid answer and 2. That won't work.

Comment: This worked: 69 #function to search for a record by last name
 70 last_search () {
 71         echo "What last name are you looking for?"
 72         read input_name
 73         echo "$input_name"
 74 #       awk -F':' '{print $0}' temp_phonebook
 75 # Searches by last name, displays results
 76         awk -F':' '$2 ~ /'$input_name'/{print $0}' temp_phonebook
 77 }

Comment: `awk -F':' '$2 ~ /'$input_name'/{print $0}' temp_phonebook 77 }` may have worked but is not correct. See my answer for details.